# I was testing nl.siegmann.epublib.epub and I am running into Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
    public class EpubReaderMainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main );
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        AssetManager am = getAssets();

        try{
            InputStream bookData = am.open("books/bookTest.epub");
            Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(bookData);          
            Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());
            Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());
            Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
                      .getInputStream());
            Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
                      + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");
            logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            // read epub file
            EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
            Book book = epubReader.readEpub(new FileInputStream("mybook.epub"));

            // print the first title
            List<String> titles = book.getMetadata().getTitles();
            String a = ("book title:" + (titles.isEmpty() ? "book has no title" : titles.get(0)));
            tv.setText(a);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tocReferences == null) {
              return;
            }
            for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
              StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
              for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                tocString.append("\t");
              }
              tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
              Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());

              logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
            }

        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
    11-21 10:51:19.570: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(325): Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.EpubReader' instead.
    11-21 10:51:19.780: D/dalvikvm(325): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1136K, 56% free 2984K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 3ms+3ms
    11-21 10:51:19.790: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(325): Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubProcessorSupport' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.EpubProces*' instead.
    11-21 10:51:19.830: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(325): Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.PackageDocumentReader' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.PackageDoc*' instead.
    11-21 10:51:19.929: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(325): Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.NCXDocument' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.NCXDocument' instead.
    11-21 10:51:19.980: I/epublib(325): author(s): [Haynes, Carrie James]
    11-21 10:51:19.980: I/epublib(325): title: Whispers of a Legend - Part One - Shadows of the Past
    11-21 10:51:19.980: D/AndroidRuntime(325): Shutting down VM
    11-21 10:51:19.980: W/dalvikvm(325): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{epub.reader/epub.reader.EpubReaderMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at epub.reader.EpubReaderMainActivity.onCreate(EpubReaderMainActivity.java:43)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  ... 11 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="epub.reader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".EpubReaderMainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have been trying for a while but I am stuck.
Here is what I tried I checked the Epublib packages if there is any requirement of a permission in order to run the activity. What this activity does is log in the .epub file and read just the first title since I am testing out their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study the trace carefully: towards the bottom you have

```
11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 10:51:19.990: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at epub.reader.EpubReaderMainActivity.onCreate(EpubReaderMainActivity.java:43)
```

Check your `onCreate` method, line 43 in the activity class file, whichever that is :)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry still new to java in general haven't spot The NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827341/have-error-when-read-epub-file-with-siegmann/14701327#14701327).The Null Pointer exception is due to partial loading of slf4 and epub libraries