# Have error when read epub file with siegmann

Tags: android, epub

I was tried to read epub file using siegmann method in this link : http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android but i have a problem, when i debug, it have an error at :

```
`Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);`
```

And when i test with the command :
    `EpubReader epub = new EpubReader();`  it still have error at that line.
Please help me!!!

Comment: and how would i assume the errors ? please upload the logcat at well.

Comment: ya, that logcat picture pink is : http://imageupload.org/getfile.php?id=227296&a=ea1d02aaac8fa10e91ba0aaa365ce2ad&t=4fc6f1cd&o=3924377C569B4DFB722B8F2B34E2BDB83D6D322F05D44AB56D2AE0776AA9A1C146243660569B&n=logcat.png&i=1

Answer (score 0):

You could put your epub file into a folder "assets" and try with this:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("bookName.epub");
Book book = new EpubReader().readEpub(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading slf4 lib files into your project.Add slf4-api and slf4-simple to slf4-android in your libs folder and add it to the build path